# B1 visa expiring after seven months?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I have a B1 visa for five years. If I do not travel to the US during seven months, will it cancelled after the seventh month?

Comment: If your B1 visa is valid for 5 years, why do you think it would be canceled after 7 months?  I'm a little confused by your question.

Answer (score 4):

No, the B1 visa does not expire if it doesn’t get used, your visa is valid for 5 years and you can use it for 5 years, unless it gets revoked.

Comment: @Djesu  No problem, if my answer helped please accept it by pressing the tick, thanks

Comment: @Djesu US visas do not require any sort of "activation". You can use them once or not at all, and enter the US at any time until and including the expiry date printed on the visa.